# How do browsers isolate traffic within a single tab?

Tags: security, networking, sockets, resources, web-browser

I know that browsers use a separate port for each tab. However, in each tab, there might be multiple scripts doing data transfer over the network. How does a browser makes sure that the data is delivered to the right script, to prevent security issues? How does it differentiates between all the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

One approach used in modern browsers is to make each tab a separate process.  That way each is effectively a separate program, and they cannot interfere with each other.  An extra process manages opening and closing tabs and provides the overall window in which the tabs operate.

Comment: Yes, but how does it differentiates between multiple scripts inside the same tab?

Answer (score 0):

Each connection is a separate entity (socket in system terms), there is no way to retrieve data from another connection on connection level.
Security checks go way later, when everything is retrieved, or before establishing connection. For example, [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) denies external scripts access to current page. TLS certificate verification, on the other hand, works before establishing connection, and warns the user if certificate is invalid or expired.

Comment: I see. So, each network connection (whether made when retrieving the web resources, or when those web resource try to transfer data) is assigned a new socket, and thus a new port? Does this mean that it is possible for a browser to run out of ports, if too many scripts make network connections at once?

Comment: @marked-off-topic, right, consider it as a system of pipes, each one goes to a distinct server and pipes are not interconnected.